# Gnuplot on Mac OS X 10.9 - X11 terminal and mouse interactivity

Tags: macos, mouse, gnuplot, x11

I've installed the Gnuplot version 4.6.6 on my MacBook with Mac OS X 10.9.5. For the X11 terminal I'm using XQuartz 2.7.7.

Everything works fine, except that the mouse functionalities, as zooming, are not working. The X11 terminal recognises the mouse, as the coordinates are updated as I move the mouse on the window, but I'm unable to zoom with the right clic. On my previous Mac (OS X 10.6.8) the mouse was working just fine...any hint?

Comment: Do you plot with `-persist`, or in a normal interactive session?

Comment: I tried with and without `-persist`, no difference

Answer (score 6):

I found the problem: Gnuplot is expecting a right-clic with the mouse, but the default settings for trackpad assume "Secondary click" by tapping with two fingers.

You can keep this setting, and just modify XQuartz settings: X11 ---> Preferences ---> input, then flag "Emulate three button mouse". In this way, by holding option or command while clicking on the the trackpad, the click is interpreted as a right-click, hence allowing one to zoom.

Answer (score 0):

You can "right-click" by touching the track pad with two fingers and pressing (i.e. clicking). In this situation you have to click the track pad and not just tap.

You can also tap with two fingers twice, keeping your two fingers on the pad after the second tap until the curser changes shape, then lift your two fingers from the pad. This action locks the track pad on secondary click. You can then use one finger to drag and draw your zoom-in box. Once you are happy tap once with one finger.